# after @ email address write

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I want to autocomplete email address after the @ in textbox static.

Html:

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-6 ">
  <label>Email</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="Email"  class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () { 
  var a1 = [
      "precisetech.com.pk"
  ];

  $("#Email").autocomplete({
      source: a1
  });  
});
```

Comment: Please ident your code properly next time. Also ensure that your code validates, this dit not before I fixed it.

Comment: thanx I have solve it